# Using varnish to cache batched backend operations

Tags: caching, varnish, mapnik

I'm using Mapnik to generate map tiles (PNG).  I have a url where tiles can be generated on-the-fly individually:

```
http://tiles.example.com/dynamic/MAPID/ZOOM/X/Y.png
```

Each map tile is 256x256 pixels.

However, generating tiles individually is expensive.  It's much more efficient to generate them batched (i.e. generate one large PNG, and split it into smaller files).  I have a URL that can do that too:

```
http://tiles.example.com/dynamic/MAPID
```

which batch generates all the tiles for a map and returns "OK" when complete, saves them to disk, from where they are available statically at:

```
http://tiles.example.com/static/MAPID/ZOOM/X/Y.png
```

which is NGINX serving raw files.

Is it possible to configure Varnish to trigger a batch generation, wait for it to complete, then cache and serve individual tiles until they expire (in my case, 5 minutes)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently varnish3 doesn't support backend fetching, this feature should be implemented in varnish4, Instead I would suggest to trigger those as cron jobs and varnish would fetch them when the first user hits the image.

I would also recommend that the generation would be done on a separate folder/file location and just move it when they are ready, would spare you the hassle of people hitting your server during the generation.